# Comma delimited parsing of XML for Filemaker XSLT

Tags: xml, parsing, xslt, filemaker

I am looking to parse a set of comma delimited image URLs for real estate data within a single xml tag and write them out as separate tags. This is way beyond my current knowledge and I am having real trouble learning what I need to do quickly enough to get this job done. If someone could help, it would be much appreciated.

Here is the XML:

```
<Report>
    <Row1>
        <Reference>001</Reference>
        <Type>House</Type>
        <Location>New York</Estado>
        <Size>665.6</Size>
        <Images>http://www.example.com/001/image1.jpg,http://www.example.com/001/image2.jpg,http://www.example.com/001/image3.jpg,http://www.example.com/001/image4.jpg</Images>
    </Row1>
    <Row2>
        <Reference>056</Reference>
        <Type>Apartment</Type>
        <Location>Washington</Estado>
        <Size>147.5</Size>
        <Images>http://www.example.com/056/image1.jpg,http://www.example.com/056/image5.jpg,http://www.example.com/056/image8.jpg,http://www.example.com/056/image9.jpg</Images>
    </Row2>
    </Report>
```

This is what I would like to output:

```
<RESULTSET>
    <ROW>
        <COL><DATA>001</DATA></COL>
        <COL><DATA>House</DATA></COL>
        <COL><DATA>New York</DATA></COL>
        <COL><DATA>665.6</DATA></COL>
        <COL><DATA>http://www.example.com/001/image1.jpg</DATA></COL>
        <COL><DATA>http://www.example.com/001/image2.jpg</DATA></COL>
        <COL><DATA>http://www.example.com/001/image3.jpg</DATA></COL>
        <COL><DATA>http://www.example.com/001/image4.jpg</DATA></COL>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <COL><DATA>056</DATA></COL>
        <COL><DATA>Apartment</DATA></COL>
        <COL><DATA>Washington</DATA></COL>
        <COL><DATA>147.5</DATA></COL>
        <COL><DATA>http://www.example.com/056/image1.jpg</DATA></COL>
        <COL><DATA>http://www.example.com/056/image5.jpg</DATA></COL>
        <COL><DATA>http://www.example.com/056/image8.jpg</DATA></COL>
        <COL><DATA>http://www.example.com/056/image9.jpg</DATA></COL>
    </ROW>
</RESULTSET>
```

Thank you for any help you can give me.

Comment: Are you working with XSLT 1.0 or 2.0?

Comment: Hi - it's 1.0. Could that be a problem?

Comment: @user3771050 Not a problem, but much easier to solve in XSLT 2.0 or +. Do you always have 4 images, or can you have more, or less?

Comment: Hi - yes I can have more or less. I forgot to make that clear. I can have up to 36 images. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All source nodes, except for the `Images` nodes, can be processed by simple templates that extract their content and reorganize it in your new structure:

```
<xsl:template match="Report">
    <RESULTSET>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </RESULTSET>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Report/*">
    <ROW>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </ROW>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Report/*/*[not(self::Images)]">
    <COL><DATA>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </DATA></COL>
</xsl:template>
```

The `Images` node requires splitting the string by a separator (`,`). To achieve this in XSLT 1.0 you need a named template that you can call recursively. It will be called by a template that matches the `Images` element:

```
<xsl:template match="Images">
    <xsl:call-template name="split">
        <xsl:with-param name="string" select="."/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
```

The named template `split` checks if there is a comma in the sequence. If not, it simply returns the contents wrapped in a `<COL><DATA>` block. If there is, the first element is extracted and the rest of the string is processed by the same template recursively, until all items are processed. The result will be a list of `<COL><DATA>` blocks each containing one item:

```
<xsl:template name="split">
    <xsl:param name="string"/>
    <xsl:param name="separator">,</xsl:param>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($string, $separator)">
                <xsl:variable name="first-string" select="substring-before($string, $separator)"/>
                <xsl:variable name="rest" select="substring-after($string, concat($first-string,$separator))"/>
                <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="$first-string"/></DATA></COL>
                <xsl:call-template name="split">
                    <xsl:with-param name="string" select="$rest"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="$string"/></DATA></COL>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

You can try it out in this **[XSLT Fiddle](http://xsltransform.net/94hvTyK)**

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay in getting back to this question. Can it be amended to include up to 36 images even if they are not provided. i.e. it fills as many fields as there is data but then gives empty fields for the rest? XSLT is such a departure to what I normally do that it's tough-going trying to learn it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's possible, but it starts to get complicated if you are limited to XSLT 1.0. You would need two other templates: one to count the images and another one to recursively loop and add empty blocks for each missing image. Probably some more 20 lines of code. 1/10 of that if you use XSLT 2.0.

Answer (score 2):

> I can have up to 36 images.

IMHO, you are taking the wrong turn here. If you can have up to 36 images, you will also need 36 fields to hold them. This is not a good structure to have. You should keep a related table for the images, where each location(?) can have **any** number of images.

To import the images, you can either import the same source document twice (using a dedicated  stylesheet for each import), or import the URLs into a **single** field first, as a return separated list, then split them up in Filemaker into individual related records. Both of these can be scripted, of course.